minted package: Julia utf 8 characters vanish
In my Julia code (filename:bell.jl)  there appear lines with special characters like
ket_labels=["|ϕ⁺⟩", "|ϕ⁻⟩", "|Ψ⁺⟩","|Ψ⁻⟩"];  
ϕ⁺ =  QBase.Ket(1/sqrt(2)*[1,0,0,1])
I am using Linux(OpenSuse, KDE, VSCode for Julia Programming)
For documentation I use TeXStudio, LuaLaTeX and Okular as PDF-Viewer.
cat bell.jl is OK
kate bell.jl is OK
even LibreOffice-Writer -> open -> bell.jl is OK
but in the resulting pdf-file all special characters like "|ϕ⁺⟩" are gone!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \begin{document}
    \inputminted{Julia}{~/workspaces/julia-wsp/Yao/bell.jl}
 \end{document}


Adding: If I use the clipboard in TeXStudio: \begin{minted}{Julia} ket_labels=["|ϕ⁺⟩", "|ϕ⁻⟩", "|Ψ⁺⟩","|Ψ⁻⟩"];   ϕ⁺ =  QBase.Ket(1/sqrt(2)*[1,0,0,1]) \end{minted}  I see the special characters in TeXStudio editor  - but not in the resulting pdf!

Another Add-on: 'pygmentize bell.jl' is OK too. I believe though minted depends on Verbatim environment this is a problem of the fancyvrb package - utf8 seems to be broken there!

With LuaLaTeX you can choose a monospaced font that supports the required glyphs.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
]

\begin{document}

Text\texttt{Text}

\begin{minted}{Julia}
ket_labels=["|ϕ⁺⟩", "|ϕ⁻⟩", "|Ψ⁺⟩","|Ψ⁻⟩"];
ϕ⁺ =  QBase.Ket(1/sqrt(2)*[1,0,0,1])
\end{minted}

\end{document}



OK - it works . Weird enough, I  thought I tried
'\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}`
already - but obviously not in this context. Thank you very much  for thinking obout my problem!

Sorry I have no reputation to increase your answer points(?). But it helps me a lot ! Thanx

@JohannAngsüsser You're welcome! I can survive also without your votes.
